# make a sum with cards

Tags: calculation-puzzle, cards

Take the numbered diamond cards in a standard deck, that is those from 2 to 10. You may use some of them to form a sum: for example 23+45=68. What is the maximum result you may obtain? I hoped there was some way to obtain 10xy, but this seems not to be the case.

Comment: Can you specify what the allowed actions are, please? Can we for example form the number 9876543210?

Comment: A single number is not a sum. You must have one or more plus signs.

Comment: answer is hidden in this answer of this question [ here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53684/the-impossible-digital-sum).

Comment: @Oray Here we are not limited to the sum of two numbers and each number is not limited to three digits. If you have a formal proof that 1098 is the biggest number we can get in this puzzle, I think this would make a very interesting answer.

Comment: @xhienne  i did not refer that part, just gave an answer from another perspective :) no other intention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions in 9 cards and 1 sum:

> $623+475=1098$ and $746+352=1098$

Comment: I did not think that a carry was not necessary to reach 1000+ in the sum :-)